# LogCat entry meaning

Tags: java, android, logcat, android-logcat

This is in my LogCat and i don't know what it means. Can somebody understand this.
Thank you!

```
12-26 17:51:04.141: W/dalvikvm(9109): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40af6300)
12-26 17:51:04.151: E/AndroidRuntime(9109): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-26 17:51:04.151: E/AndroidRuntime(9109): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.to_doliste/com.example.to_doliste.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
12-26 17:51:04.151: E/AndroidRuntime(9109):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2243)
12-26 17:51:04.151: E/AndroidRuntime(9109):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
12-26 17:51:04.151: E/AndroidRuntime(9109):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:142)
12-26 17:51:04.151: E/AndroidRuntime(9109):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280)
12-26 17:51:04.151: E/AndroidRuntime(9109):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-26 17:51:04.151: E/AndroidRuntime(9109):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
12-26 17:51:04.151: E/AndroidRuntime(9109):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5099)
12-26 17:51:04.151: E/AndroidRuntime(9109):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-26 17:51:04.151: E/AndroidRuntime(9109):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-26 17:51:04.151: E/AndroidRuntime(9109):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
12-26 17:51:04.151: E/AndroidRuntime(9109):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
12-26 17:51:04.151: E/AndroidRuntime(9109):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-26 17:51:04.151: E/AndroidRuntime(9109): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
12-26 17:51:04.151: E/AndroidRuntime(9109):     at android.app.ListActivity.onContentChanged(ListActivity.java:250)
12-26 17:51:04.151: E/AndroidRuntime(9109):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:281)
12-26 17:51:04.151: E/AndroidRuntime(9109):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1897)
12-26 17:51:04.151: E/AndroidRuntime(9109):     at com.example.to_doliste.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17)
12-26 17:51:04.151: E/AndroidRuntime(9109):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4543)
12-26 17:51:04.151: E/AndroidRuntime(9109):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1071)
12-26 17:51:04.151: E/AndroidRuntime(9109):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2199)
12-26 17:51:04.151: E/AndroidRuntime(9109):     ... 11 more
12-26 17:53:16.211: W/dalvikvm(10189): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40af6300)
12-26 17:53:16.221: E/AndroidRuntime(10189): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-26 17:53:16.221: E/AndroidRuntime(10189): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.to_doliste/com.example.to_doliste.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
12-26 17:53:16.221: E/AndroidRuntime(10189):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2243)
12-26 17:53:16.221: E/AndroidRuntime(10189):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
12-26 17:53:16.221: E/AndroidRuntime(10189):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:142)
12-26 17:53:16.221: E/AndroidRuntime(10189):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280)
12-26 17:53:16.221: E/AndroidRuntime(10189):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-26 17:53:16.221: E/AndroidRuntime(10189):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
12-26 17:53:16.221: E/AndroidRuntime(10189):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5099)
12-26 17:53:16.221: E/AndroidRuntime(10189):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-26 17:53:16.221: E/AndroidRuntime(10189):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-26 17:53:16.221: E/AndroidRuntime(10189):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
12-26 17:53:16.221: E/AndroidRuntime(10189):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
12-26 17:53:16.221: E/AndroidRuntime(10189):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-26 17:53:16.221: E/AndroidRuntime(10189): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
12-26 17:53:16.221: E/AndroidRuntime(10189):    at android.app.ListActivity.onContentChanged(ListActivity.java:250)
12-26 17:53:16.221: E/AndroidRuntime(10189):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:281)
12-26 17:53:16.221: E/AndroidRuntime(10189):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1897)
12-26 17:53:16.221: E/AndroidRuntime(10189):    at com.example.to_doliste.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17)
12-26 17:53:16.221: E/AndroidRuntime(10189):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4543)
12-26 17:53:16.221: E/AndroidRuntime(10189):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1071)
12-26 17:53:16.221: E/AndroidRuntime(10189):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2199)
12-26 17:53:16.221: E/AndroidRuntime(10189):    ... 11 more
12-26 17:56:31.941: W/dalvikvm(12002): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40af6300)
12-26 17:56:31.951: E/AndroidRuntime(12002): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-26 17:56:31.951: E/AndroidRuntime(12002): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.to_doliste/com.example.to_doliste.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
12-26 17:56:31.951: E/AndroidRuntime(12002):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2243)
12-26 17:56:31.951: E/AndroidRuntime(12002):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
12-26 17:56:31.951: E/AndroidRuntime(12002):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:142)
12-26 17:56:31.951: E/AndroidRuntime(12002):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280)
12-26 17:56:31.951: E/AndroidRuntime(12002):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-26 17:56:31.951: E/AndroidRuntime(12002):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
12-26 17:56:31.951: E/AndroidRuntime(12002):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5099)
12-26 17:56:31.951: E/AndroidRuntime(12002):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-26 17:56:31.951: E/AndroidRuntime(12002):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-26 17:56:31.951: E/AndroidRuntime(12002):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
12-26 17:56:31.951: E/AndroidRuntime(12002):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
12-26 17:56:31.951: E/AndroidRuntime(12002):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-26 17:56:31.951: E/AndroidRuntime(12002): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
12-26 17:56:31.951: E/AndroidRuntime(12002):    at android.app.ListActivity.onContentChanged(ListActivity.java:250)
12-26 17:56:31.951: E/AndroidRuntime(12002):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:281)
12-26 17:56:31.951: E/AndroidRuntime(12002):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1897)
12-26 17:56:31.951: E/AndroidRuntime(12002):    at com.example.to_doliste.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17)
12-26 17:56:31.951: E/AndroidRuntime(12002):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4543)
12-26 17:56:31.951: E/AndroidRuntime(12002):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1071)
12-26 17:56:31.951: E/AndroidRuntime(12002):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2199)
12-26 17:56:31.951: E/AndroidRuntime(12002):    ... 11 more
12-26 17:56:33.251: D/Process(12002): killProcess, pid=12002
12-26 17:56:33.251: D/Process(12002): dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace(Native Method)
12-26 17:56:33.251: D/Process(12002): java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:599)
12-26 17:56:33.251: D/Process(12002): android.os.Process.killProcess(Process.java:813)
12-26 17:56:33.251: D/Process(12002): com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:104)
12-26 17:56:33.251: D/Process(12002): java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
12-26 17:56:33.251: D/Process(12002): java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
```

Comment: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
17:56:31.951: E/AndroidRuntime(12002): 
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list' 
12-26 17:56:31.951: E/AndroidRuntime(12002): at android.app.ListActivity.onContentChanged(ListActivity.java:250) 12-26 17:56:31.951: E/AndroidRuntime(12002): at
```

It seems you are trying to use ListView but there is no entry with id `list` in `xml`.

```
<ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
         ....../>
```

Comment: Thank you, now I know where i have to look in LogCat!

Answer (score 6):

here

> Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is
>   'android.R.id.list' 12-26 17:51:04.151: E/AndroidRuntime(9109): at

means you must set your ListView id to list in xml layout as:

```
<ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Usuually just look for the "caused by" in the error message:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content 
must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
```

You must give your custom list view xml layout file the expected list id so that it can find it.

```
android:id="@android:id/list"
```